# Android App that draws a path as user moves(Using Google Maps SDK)

Tags: java, android, google-maps

It is drawing a polyline based on where the user was and now is but for some reason it creates another line which points from the new LatLng to the Origin(Where the user started) LatLng

I am trying to figure out why but I am struggling to find the problem in my code
[As you can see it draws a line as the user moves but on each new latlng it draws this really straight line to the latlng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxuYc.jpg)

***Please Note: Yes I know some of the code I am using in LocationRequest is deprecated I will update it in the final version***

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private PolylineOptions polylineOptions;
    private Polyline polyline;
    private List<LatLng> points;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if (location != null) {
                            LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));
                            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                        }
                    }
                });
        points = new ArrayList<>();
        polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        polylineOptions.width(5);
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                if (locationResult != null) {
                    Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    points.add(latLng);
                    polylineOptions.addAll(points);
                    if (polyline != null) {
                        polyline.remove();
                    }
                    polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        return locationRequest;
    }

}
```

In Theory:
The app should draw a simple polyline based on where the user was and where they are now(simple right?)

Reality:
It is drawing a polyline based on where the user was and now is but for some reason it creates another line which points from the new LatLng to the Origin(Where the user started) LatLng

Tried:
Tried to find anything on the google docs even tried ChatGPT(not going to lie) but I can't find a solution.